# How to make multiple reusable widgets in flutter in one class?

Tags: flutter, widget, code-reuse

I know how to make one item-widget in a class and use it throughout app, something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuButtons extends StatelessWidget {

  final String titleName;
  final String goTo;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  MenuButtons(this.titleName,{this.goTo, this.width, this.height});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      width: width,
      height: height !=null ? height : 50.0,

      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(121, 85, 72, 1.0),
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: Text(
          titleName,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () {

           Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, goTo);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
MenuButtons('Title',goTo: 'NextScreen',width: 350.0,),
```

Now if I want to have more widgets can I use the same class but maybe with different constructor or do I need a separate class for each widget I want to use in multiple places...

Answer (score 0):

if the new class just has some params not related to build method, you can declare like this, for example new class IndexMenuButtons

```
class IndexMenuButtons extends MenuButtons{
   final int buttonIndex;
   ColorMenuButtons(String titleName, this.buttonIndex, {String goTo, double width, double height}) : super(titleName, goTo, width, height);
}
```

Usage:

```
var btn = IndexMenuButtons('Title', 100, goTo: 'NextScreen',width: 350.0);
```